# sizeof(struct ExampleStruct) or sizeof( *VarExampleStruct) - Which is a better coding practice?

Tags: c, structure

While mentioning the size of a structure to a malloc call, is it better to mention the name of the structure or the dereferenced structure pointer variable?

Example:

```
struct ExampleStruct
{
  int x;
  char arr[40];
};

int main()
{

  struct ExampleStruct *Y = NULL;

  Y = malloc(sizeof(struct ExampleStruct)); //Is this better?

  Y = malloc(sizeof(*Y)); //Is this better?  

}
```

I personally prefer `sizeof(struct ExampleStruct)` as I have seen many developers making the mistake missing the '*' in the second method, i.e. they erroneously type it as `malloc(sizeof(Y))` and in this case, the memory allocated will be only 4 bytes. But, I have seen it being used commonly also.

Comment: Just for the record, the user Jay who has made a number of comments is different from the user Jay who asked the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer, Thanks for the clarifying. I am the one who has posted the question and I am not the one commenting and answering. : )

Comment: How can that happen? Normally, having a user name which is already given should be blocked from the system...

Comment: @Jay (The one with lots of comments here): Just a 'request' to tone down your somewhat aggresive comments. I just thought of initiating a healthy discussion and getting an opinion, so I could provide some guideline for coding in my team. Thanks.

Comment: @glglgl: SO allows people to choose (and change) the name that is shown, and multiple people can have the same name.  The default icons are generated from your email address; sometimes, you'll find two user numbers with the same icon.  The user number is the 'real' identifier; the name is just a convenient (but not necessarily unique) handle for the number.

Comment: @glglgl, I am surprised too - Jay (The one who posted the question) : (

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is very fine for distinguishing people :-( Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked in K&R 2nd Edition, and found 3 relevant examples of using `malloc()`:

- Page 142: `return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));`
- Page 145: `np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));`
- Page 146: `return (Treeptr) malloc(sizeof(Treenode));`

There was no particular discussion of the different forms.  There's a note in the preface 'We used Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ translator extensively for local testing of our programs'.  This was written just before the 1989 C Standard was finalized (my copy has 'Based on the Draft Proposed ANSI C' on the cover, so there were no standard compilers at the time), and this may explain the explicit casts on every `malloc()` call — those are necessary in C++.

So, the 'founders' used both forms.

Modern style is to use the `sizeof(*variable)` notation (and, in C, to omit the cast) so that even if the type of the variable changes, you won't have to change this code.  Add the cast, and that benefit goes away.

Most of my older code tends to use the `sizeof(type)` notation, in part in emulation of the style in K&R C.  Most of my newer code now uses the `sizeof(*variable)` notation.  When I expect to compile the code with C++ as well as C, I put the cast in too.

Comment: The cast of `malloc` in K&R comes from pre-ANSI where the cast was required. There is an interesting mention in the K&R2nd errata (truncated due to SO): *"The remark about casting the return value of malloc [...] needs to be rewritten. The example is correct and works, but the advice is debatable in the context of the 1988-1989 ANSI/ISO standards. It's not necessary [...] and possibly harmful if malloc, or a proxy for it, fails to be declared as returning void *. The explicit cast can cover up an unintended error. On the other hand, pre-ANSI, the cast was necessary [...]"*

Answer (score 5):

I definitely prefer the 2nd. If the declared type of `Y` every changes, the line will still work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
Y = malloc(sizeof(struct ExampleStruct));
```

Because, this is the data type, you can multiply it for another purpose.
ex:

```
Y = malloc(sizeof(struct ExampleStruct) * 5);
```

ex:

```
int *i;
```

I'd prefer:

```
i = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

than,

```
i = malloc(sizeof(*i);
```

And also, as a reminder, this variable `i` is a pointer to `int`, and `Y` is a pointer to `struct ExampleStruct`.

Comment: You can just as easily write `malloc(sizeof(*Y) * 5)` and it works fine.

Comment: yes, it's true.. But i prefer using the data type.. moreover if already use typedef..

Comment: @ Jonathan, please see my comment below... I beg to disagree

Answer (score 1):

The typical argument for the second is that when the type of Y changes, the `malloc()` still works. However, usually there's initialization code following the statement, initializing the old type of Y. You have to at least review it if it is still working for the new type. There is much more planning involved for a type change to "just work".

But additionally, the second is usually less code to write and less code to read later.

I prefer to go a step further and use Create and Destroy functions for such cases. The Create function doesn't return a void pointer, but the correct type. So if the type of Y changes, but I don't change the call (and review the following initialization code), then the compiler gives me an error.

Plus, this makes resource management much easier than throwing random `malloc()` and `free()` calls all over your code.